# Calculte new width and height of the video based on the original width, height and ratio

Tags: resize, geometry, aspect-ratio, calculus

After searching through - I wasn't able to find the answer so I'll give it a shot here.

I need to resize desktop video in order to feet it on mobile screen, let's say original width of the video was 1915 and original height was 1075, I calculated aspect ratio:

```
aspectRatio = (width/height); aspectRatio = 1.78;
```

Now my mobile screen resolution is: height = 1609, width = 1080.

How can I properly resize my video in order to keep the same aspect ratio??

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

aspectRatio = (width/height)

You always want aspectRatio to be 1.78, if you want to prevent stretching or cropping.

And, the max new height is 1609 and the max new width is 1080, so:

1.78 = (1080/height)
height = 1080/1.78 = 606.74...

OR

1.78 = (width/1609)
width = 1.78*1609 = 2864.02...

So, you can have 1080x606.74 (which fits on screen), or 2864.02x1609 (which doesn't fit).

So, your answer is 1080x606.74...

Answer (score 0):

Let's original dimensions are Wo, Ho, and target screen dimensions are Wt, Ht.
Rectangle with predetermined aspect will fit vertically if ratio of target and initial heights less than ratio of its widths, and will fit horizontally otherwise:

```
Coeff = Min(Wt/Wo, Ht/Ho)
W_Result = Wo * Coeff
H_Result = Ho * Coeff
```

or

```
if (Wt * Ho < Ht * Wo) then
    W_Result = Wt
    H_Result = Ho * Wt / Wo
else
    W_Result = Wo * Ht / Ho
    H_Result = Ht
```